# How to insert reference to local image to html and show it in label swift?

Tags: swift, uilabel

In my assets folder I have `en` folder and here I have some pictures, for example one of them - `B12.png`. I can't understand how to show this local picture in my label. I have such code:

```
let imageData:Data =  (UIImage.init(named: "en/B12.png")!).pngData()!
let base64String = imageData.base64EncodedString()

                            
let htmlString = """
<html><body><img src="data:image/png;base64, \(base64String)" /> width=\"360\" height=\"240\"></body></html>
"""
                            
                            
cell.questionText.attributedText = htmlString.convertToAttributedFromHTML()
```

but when I run this code I don't see anything in my label. Why does it happen and how I can solve this problem?

Comment: Just insert the image URL. Create the URL with the path obtained from `Bundle.main.path(forResource: ofType:)`

Comment: @mag_zbc, can you add some details please, because I have some difficulties with your comment :)

Answer (score 1):

If your image is store in your app's bundle, you can simply insert the image's URL

```
if let imagePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "B12", ofType: "png") {
    let htmlString = """
    <html><body><img src="\(imagePath)" /> width=\"360\" height=\"240\"></body></html>
    """

    cell.questionText.attributedText = htmlString.convertToAttributedFromHTML()
}
```

Comment: I have such error - `Non-void function should return a value`, and I don't see how to use sub folder for picture :(

Comment: Updated my answer. As for sub-folders, it doesn't matter. `Bundle.main.path(forResource: "B12", ofType: "png")` will find your image regardles of location, as long as it is anywhere in application's bundle.

Comment: I have pictures with similar names but with different content, will it work for such scheme?

Comment: and also another problem is that my cell label becomes invisible when I add this html to it

Comment: As I see your if condition usually false and it doesn’t work

Comment: So some of your images work, and some don't? Do your image files have a proper `Target Membership` set? Can you see them in `Project Settings > Build Phases > Copy Bundle Resources`?

Comment: right now I'm testing one picture, but I will need to handle localization of device and load proper image, I don't know about `Target ...` and also I didn't look in `Project Settings > Build Phases > Copy Bundle Resources` what it will solve?